# How to use GCMathParser in iOS 5 application (XCode 4.2) with ARC?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, automatic-ref-counting

After changing 
 -  `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` to `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` 
 - "pi" to "M_PI" 
and disabling ARC for the GCMathParser files, I get the following error: (multiple places)

> Cast of C pointer type "void*" to Objective-C pointer type "GCMathParser*" requires a bridged cast

What do I have to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARC doesn't let you hide objects behind untyped pointers -- it needs to know which pointers are objects in order to do its magic. If you're dealing with a framework that relies heavily on that trick, you may have to do a fair amount of re-architecting it. Not fun.

You might try [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki) instead; it's functionally similar, more extensible, and supports ARC and iOS "out of the box".

Comment: thanks. i tried DDMathParser and i managed to solve what i had to do.