# Linking error using DDMathParser (iOS 5, Xcode 4.2)

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, mathematical-expressions, linker-errors, ddmathparser

I try to add DDMathParser library to my project, but i get two linking errors. I'm a newbie in Objective-C programming, and it's still tricky for me.
Below there is a snapshot of the errors i get: [image]

What should i do?

I also tried CGMathParser but i didn't manage to solve some errors i get.

[I asked here, but i didn't get any feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850698/how-to-use-gcmathparser-in-ios-5-application-xcode-4-2-with-arc)

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've copied in the headers, but not actually linked the source files in.  In other words, Xcode isn't compiling DDMathParser into your project.

This page on the DDMathParser wiki has information on what you're supposed to do: https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Adding-DDMathParser-to-your-project